# Fastest way to parse multiple header names to Plotly (Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly

so I've been experimenting with plotly and trying to get plotting multiple traces. I wrote the following code which plots two traces on the same graph :

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
headers = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col=0, nrows=0).columns.tolist()
fig = go.Figure()

fig = px.line(data, x="DateTime", y=[headers[0], headers[1]])
fig.show()
```

In this example the first and second headers are plotted as traces on the graph. I was wondering if there was a way other than y=[headers[n],headers[n+1]]... to get all the lines drawn on? I tried just using the headers array without an index, but it gives a ValueError
`Plotly Express cannot process wide-form data with columns of different type.`

So, is there a plotly-specific way to make this more efficient & readable than just writing every index in the plot header definition, or can it be done with standard python?

EDIT: the actual data sample is a csv providing int values with a header and date :

```
DateTime    X Y Z
01-JAN-2018,5,6,7...
02-JAN-2018,7,8,9
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `data` in the question?

Comment: Can you change the data types to be the same?

Comment: @DerekO data added

Comment: @JonathanLeon I don't think I can, because I need multiple headers in an array, but the function only wants single strings. I can't find a way to use a loop to add the headers to the plot, so I'd have to write headers[n],headers[n+1]... as in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your sample data is what is in your CSV, it's a simple case of defining **y** as the numeric columns

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
headers = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""DateTime,X,Y,Z
01-JAN-2018,5,6,7
02-JAN-2018,7,8,9
"""))

px.line(headers, x="DateTime", y=headers.select_dtypes("number").columns)
```

[image]